# Google Maps API v3 Combinatorics: Shortest Route With Many People, Many Locations

Tags: google-maps, gwt, google-maps-api-3, routes, gwt-2.5

Unfortunately, I am missing an idea to solve the following problem:

I have 20 locations, which have to be visited one time, and 4 persons, who manage the routes.  Also, I have the same origin and the same destination for each driver.

Now, I want...

- Everyone to drive approximately the same time
- Every location to be visited just one time, it does not matter who it is.
- The amount of time and length for all 4 routes **summed up** to be minimal,
  that means, it is not absolutely necessary, that **one single** route is optimal.

I only know how to shorten one single route (`setOptimizeWaypoints:true`) and how to work with waypoints... distance matrix... etc. so I have not any clue how to combine more than one route.

I use maps API v3 in GWT 2.5.1., but I am also experienced in pure JavaScript. Any ideas?

Comment: As Google API cannot solve directly your problem you will have to throw more API queries and then select optimal combination on your own e.g. you will have to filter path which will cover all 20 locations and in total travel time will be minimal... it won`t be easy.

Comment: Possible duplicate `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239148/travelling-salesman-with-multiple-salesmen`

Answer (score 0):

That's not a problem you'll be able to solve with the right call to the API. Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem

Comment: i already read about the "travelling salesman problem", with does not tell anything about how to split everything up to 4 persons. :/