# How to twist K-Means algorithm in R to find optimal assignment of service personal

Tags: r, algorithm, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a list (say 300) of customers (lat,long)- and a list (say 10) of service engineers (lat,long). I need to assign a service engineer for each customer in an optimal way. To reduce his travel and increase his capacity of attending customers. Assume he has to attend all customers on a regular basis.
Trying for a K means clustering , which should divide the customers into 10 clusters and assign the service engineer for each customer. Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: While this is far from definitive, it looks like the authors of [this final project](https://www.math.cmu.edu/~af1p/Teaching/OR2/Projects/P12/2010FinalProject.pdf) found clustering to not be the best approach to the multiple travelling salesmen problem. I would look for a metaheuristic approach

Comment: See more discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239148/travelling-salesman-with-multiple-salesmen)

Comment: [Another approach](http://www.naturalspublishing.com/files/published/00r020bk1121qr.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Clustering is totally the *wrong approach* here. It does not balance the sets, but rather if 99% of your customers are close to each other, they will be assigned the same cluster. Furthermore, k-means cannot use geo distances, and assumes your center can move to any desired location.

Rather than looking at clustering, you need to look at **resource allocation**, for example the famous [hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm).